# Can delete some lines on build.gradle (app)

Tags: android, build.gradle, release

Should I delete this lines in build.gradle (app) before create the release version?

```
    android {
    ...
    <!-- This one -->
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dependencies {
    ...
    <!-- this block -->
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

       <!-- and this line -->
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

I'm in doubt 'cause if them are related with project test should I deleted them, shouldn't I? This way my code will be more protected, won't be?

And can I simply deleted them? This won't affect the rest of code?

Thx

Comment: There's no need - gradle is used to build releases. It's not included in the releases.

Comment: @Ken Wolf If it do not include in release then whatever delete or not?

Comment: if you delete it you won't be able to run tests... Why do you want to delete it?

Comment: @Ken Wolf Actually I do not use test. I test my projects of other way. My doubt is if I let them then my code can will be "tested"/verified by others after the release? I'm new on this. Just a curious...

Comment: Delete it then!

Comment: @Ken Wolf Really thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> androidTestCompile

Its all about unit testing its not `force` require at `release` time. you can delete it,

> testInstrumentationRunner

An Instrumentation that runs various types of TestCases against an Android package

So both are for **Unit testing** purpose. you can discard it when u release or if you not playing with unit testing you can delete when you **create Your new project**.

Answer (score 2):

**There's no need** to delete them.

Since they are related to unit tests they are not included in the release builds.

If you are not using tests they are useless​ but in general it is not a good idea to remove them from `build.gradle` since you can use them also after a release build specially if you have a continuous integration environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use automatic tests with expresso, you can delete it